# Checkbox prop() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to check/uncheck a checkbox using jQuery 1.12. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-agree').click(function() {
    $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked', true);
  });
  $('#btn-notagree').click(function() {
    $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="checkbox-3" />
<button id="btn-agree">I Agree</button>
<button id="btn-notagree">Cancel</button>
```

When I click `btn-agree`, the function doesn't return any errors, but the checkbox is not checked. `console.log($('#checkbox-3').prop('checked');` show `true`

Can anyone point out what's wrong in my code?

**edit**
I believe the problem comes from somewhere else in my project. please feel free to delete this question.

Comment: You are bind event with only `btn-agree` use `$('#btn-notagree')` for binding second click handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: @Satpal oh right. sorry, I wrote the wrong code. the second one was supposed to be #btn-notagree

Comment: @jkris yes, I've seen that thread before. that's why I'm confused as why this code doesn't work

Comment: I've put your code in a snippet. As you can see it works absolutely fine. The only reason I can see this not working is that you didn't wrap it in a document.ready handler.

Comment: Your code seems to be working -_-

Comment: @PranavCBalan the problem persists even after the typo is fixed.. any ideas?

Comment: ok I believe the problem is somewhere else in the code spaghetti. I'll just leave this problem for another day. thanks for the quick responses though..

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this,that is chekc whether the checkbox is checked and if so uncheck it else check it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="checkbox-3"/>
<button id="btn-agree">I Agree</button>
<button id="btn-notagree">Cancel</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-agree').click(function() {
    if($('#checkbox-3').prop('checked'))
    $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked',false);
  else{
    $('#checkbox-3').prop('checked',true);
    }
  });
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `is(':checked')` to check whether the checkbox checked or not checked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-agree').click(function() {
        if($("#checkbox-3").is(':checked') )
        {
            $("#checkbox-3").prop('checked',false);
        }            
        else
        {
            $("#checkbox-3").prop('checked',true); 
        }                    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="checkbox-3"/>
<button id="btn-agree">I Agree</button>
<button id="btn-notagree">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="checkbox-3"/>
<button id="btn-agree">I Agree</button>
<button id="btn-notagree">Cancel</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-agree').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
  });
$('#btn-notagree').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked',false);
  });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: why are both event bindings set the prop to false?

Comment: Please check it now.